# messagex = int((SCREENWIDTH - GAME_SPRITES['message'].get_height())/2 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
playerx = int(SCREENWIDTH/5)
playery = int((SCREENHEIGHT - GAME_SPRITES['player'].get_height())/2
messagex = int((SCREENWIDTH - GAME_SPRITES['message'].get_height())/2
messagey = int(SCREENHEIGHT*0.13)
basex = 0
```

while i was using pygame, i faced this issue-

```
 messagex = int((SCREENWIDTH - GAME_SPRITES['message'].get_height())/2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please note that syntax errors are generally off topic for Stackoverflow - [help] . You've given 5 lines of code, so maybe _rewriting them carefully_ would fix the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
playery = int((SCREENHEIGHT - GAME_SPRITES['player'].get_height())/2
messagex = int((SCREENWIDTH - GAME_SPRITES['message'].get_height())/2
```

Those lines have an incorrect number of parentheses.  They have three `(`, but only two `)`.